# Android Studio turn off this warning instead of putting suppress: PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to turn off this warning `PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE` on **Android Studio** settings?

This happens in subclass `Child` when the parameter name of override method 
 changes:

```
abstract class Parent {

    abstract fun method(param: Param)
}
```

```
class Child: Parent {
    override fun method(renamedParam: Param) { //renamedParam gives me the warning
        // more code
    }
}
```

Any suggestions that will remove the yellow warning?

Comment: @zoe, this question is about android studio Code inspection. Please don’t remove the related tag, ok?

Comment: @shizhen linting isn't technically done exclusively by Android Studio. Gradle also includes linting. In this case, the linting is actually done by the Kotlin linter, which, again, isn't Android Studio. The point being, the AS code inspection isn't technically AS' code inspection, it's just built on top of different systems. I originally thought it asked how to fix it, which would justify removing the tag. You are right though.

Comment: @zoe, Is it really meaningful that you keep “cleaning” tags? Won’t it be better keep all the related tags to make the question more visible so that the asker can get helped as fast as possible?

Comment: @shizhen no. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561) (if that's true, the inverse must be as well), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging) if you're not sure how tagging works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below annotation at the top of your file in question:

```
@file:Suppress("PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE")
```

Or configure the options from below (**Preferences**->**Editor**->**Inspections**) by typing key words: `Parameter name differs from` in the search box:

[image]

Select the *Severity* to **No highlighting, only fix** in **All Scope**.

Comment: I've already tried this, but it still shows the warning. Tried also reopening android studio, still didn't work. Is there anything I should do maybe? I also guess this is the right settings for this.

Comment: It looks this option only works for Java but not Kotlin.

Comment: ohh that's unfortunate. Maybe I'll wait more if there's any workaround for this. If not, I'll mark this as the correct answer but indicate first the this works only "for Java but not Kotlin"